# How to set Webview link color from resource

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I have some HTML that I'm loading into a `WebView` and I need to customize the css styles. When it came to setting the link color directly from my Color resource I had some trouble. In the following example using `linkColorManual` worked but if I switched it to `linkColor` the css style was ignored:

```
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "utf-8";
String linkColor = getResources().getString(R.color.Link_Colour);
String linkColorManual = "#867970";
String html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>\n<html>\n<head>\n<style>\n"
        + "body, html { font-family: 'sans-serif'; font-size:14px; color:#8B8D90;}\n"
        + "a {color:"+linkColorManual+";}\n"
        + "</style>\n</head>\n<body>" + post.getPostData().toString() + "</body>\n</html>";
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.post_content);
myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(post.getPostURL().toString(), html, mime, encoding, null);
```

This is the relevant line from my `color.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <color name="Link_Colour">#867970</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

I'd rather not copy paste this hex color throughout my app. Why does it fail to apply the css if I load the color string directly from the resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

When retrieving an Android Color resource via `getResources().getString()`, I received an 8 character hex color **NOT** a 6 digit one that CSS can parse. From the example above this meant:

```
linkColor = #ff867970;
linkColorManual = #867970;
```

The extra two characters (`#ff`) at the front represent the Alpha (see [Android Color](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color) docs for more info). To retrieve the 6 character CSS parsable color instead, I used the following:

```
int linkColorInt = getResources().getColor(R.color.Link_Colour);
String linkColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(linkColorInt & 0x00FFFFFF);
```

Comment: from #00FF00 defined in my colors.xml with your solution am just gettin  #FF00

Answer (score 0):

You should just put your color in strings.xml like this:

```
<string name="Link_Colour">#223344</string>
```

Or if you want to stick with color, do this

```
int color = getResource().getColor(R.color.xyz);
String linkColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(color)
```

Comment: While this solution works, it means I would have to duplicate my hex colors - have one stored in `color.xml` and another stored in `strings.xml` because I still need to access `Link_Colour` Color for other UI elements throughout the app.